# How to reimport module from a different folder in the python code?

Tags: python

```
from config import worker
```

This is my import. In my code, I want to check if /better_config folder is available, if it does I want to reimport worker from /better_config. Is this possible with importlib.reload()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to go is:

```
try:
    from better_config import worker
except ImportError:
    from config import worker
```

Reloading is intended to refresh the same module after code update and not to import a different one.